# StaticInjectorError(a)[t -> t]: NullInjectorError: No provider for t

Tags: angular, electron

I am using Angular 8 with Electron to build a desktop application. I am using nebular theme and have created 2 custom modules and so far they are working fine but i created a sharedModule to export a component from one module for another module but on clicking the respective component making use of that shared Module it started showing me this error

> StaticInjectorError(a)[t -> t]: 
>     StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[t -> t]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for t!
>   Here is my code

Shared Module

```
import { DropdownButtonsComponent } from '../ui-features/buttons/dropdown-buttons/dropdown-button.component';
import { NbCardModule } from '@nebular/theme';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ThemeModule } from '../../@theme/theme.module';

@NgModule({

    imports: [
      ThemeModule,
      NbCardModule
    ],
    exports: [
      DropdownButtonsComponent,
    ],
    declarations: [
      DropdownButtonsComponent,
    ],
    providers: [],
  })

  export class SharedModule { 
  }
```

Users Module

```
@NgModule({
    imports : [
        ThemeModule,
        NbCardModule,
        FormsModule, 
        UsersRoutingModule,
        SharedModule
      //  DropdownButtonsComponent
    ],
    declarations: [
        AllusersComponent, 
        UsersComponent, 
        AdduserComponent
    ]
})
export class UsersModule { }
```

Buttons Module

```
const components = [
  ButtonsComponent,
  ActionGroupsComponent,
  // DropdownButtonsComponent,
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ThemeModule,
    SharedModule,
    NbCardModule
  ],
  exports: [
    ...components,
  ],
  declarations: [
    ...components,
  ],
  providers: [],
})
export class ButtonsModule { }
```

Comment: this error related to inject a service without add that service to the provider list , current code doesn't show any use of any service , is possible to share more of your code